# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hello] associated with context path [/HelloWorldStrut2]

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts2 programming, i am trying to make simple struts2 helloworld application but getting this error please help.

Error: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hello] associated with context path [/HelloWorldStrut2].

Action class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class HelloWorldAction implements Action {

    private String name;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
            "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
        <package name = "default" namespace="/" extends = "struts-default">
         <action name = "hello" class = "com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction">
             <result name = "success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
          </action>
       </package>
    </struts>
```

**Calling jsp, index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
      <form action ="hello">
         <label for = "name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
         <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Say Hello"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelloWorldStrut2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**In pom.xml, dependencies for struts 2**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you also post your struts.xml and your JSP?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Just the action isn't helpful; it's the web app setup and S2 mappings that matter the most. I'd also consider searching the web for this as it's a common beginner's problem.

Comment: please post your struts.xml and web.xml

Comment: i have add my struts.xml, jsp and web.xml please let me know why i am facing this issue

Comment: You need to change the form action tag <s:form action="hello" > and         <s:submit id="submitId" value="Say Hello" />

Comment: Hi tried with the above comment then also it is giving the same issue @SajidHussain

Comment: thank you every one my issue resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure struts-tag.tld added in project.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelloWorldStrut2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>
              struts-default.xml,../struts.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/struts-tags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>//WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
      <s:form action="hello">
         <label for = "name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
         <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
         <s:submit id="submitId" value = "Say Hello"/>
      </s:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
      <s:property value="name"/>
   </body>
</html>
```